# lodash uniqBy not uniqing on id field

Tags: node.js, lodash

Here is my code using lodash

```
console.log('stackList2', stackList2);
console.log('stackList2.length', stackList2.length);
var stackList3 = _.uniqBy(stackList2, '_id');
console.log('stackList3', stackList3);
```

here is the output

```
stackList2 [ { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66,
               entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
               keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
               expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z,
               tags: [ 'memory' ] },
            { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68,
              entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
              keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
              expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z,
              tags: [ 'memory' ] },
            { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66,
              entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
              keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
              expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z,
              tags: [ 'memory' ] },
            { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68,
              entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
              keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
              expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z,
              tags: [ 'memory' ] } ]
stackList2.length 4
stackList3 [ { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66,
               entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
               keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
               expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z,
               tags: [ 'memory' ] },
             { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68,
               entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
               keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
               expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z,
               tags: [ 'memory' ] },
             { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66,
               entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
               keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
               expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z,
               tags: [ 'memory' ] },
             { _id: 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68,
               entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
               keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
               expiry: 2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z,
               tags: [ 'memory' ] } ]
```

As you can see stackList2 and stackList3 are exactly same. I was expecting stackList3 to contain only two objects with unique ids 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66 and 5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68

Thanks

Comment: make `_id` and `expiry` a string like '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68` and '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z' then `uniqBy` will work

Comment: okay, currently _id is objectId coming out as a result of mongoDB query. I can use a function in uniqBy to convert  _Id to string, but then I loose the nice terseness of property shorthand. But I guess this is the only way.

Comment: var stackList3 = _.uniqBy(stackList2, function(o) {
                  return String(o._id);

                });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. The _id and expiry should be string otherwise, it won't be valid.

```
> list = [
...     {
...         _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66',
...         entities: ['1tb', 'memory'],
...         keyPhrases: ['a usb memory stick', 'cheap'],
...         expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z',
...         tags: ['memory']
...     },
...     {
...         _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68',
...         entities: ['3tb', 'pankaj'],
...         keyPhrases: ['stick', 'pkpk'],
...         expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z',
...         tags: ['memory']
...     },
...     {
...         _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66',
...         entities: ['1tb', 'memory'],
...         keyPhrases: ['a usb memory stick', 'cheap'],
...         expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z',
...         tags: ['memory']
...     },
...     {
...         _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68',
...         entities: ['3tb', 'pankaj'],
...         keyPhrases: ['stick', 'pkpk'],
...         expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z',
...         tags: ['memory']
...     }
... ];
[ { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66',
    entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] },
  { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68',
    entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] },
  { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66',
    entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] },
  { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68',
    entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] } ]
> var _ = require('lodash')
> _.uniqBy(list, '_id')
[ { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd66',
    entities: [ '1tb', 'memory' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'a usb memory stick', 'cheap' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.727Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] },
  { _id: '5a745c25d8e58a4dddafcd68',
    entities: [ '3tb', 'pankaj' ],
    keyPhrases: [ 'stick', 'pkpk' ],
    expiry: '2026-02-02T12:40:05.732Z',
    tags: [ 'memory' ] } ]
```